# Как выводить каждое N-ое значение в графике?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, анализ-данных

Имеется файл CSV:

```
Отсчеты;Канал 0, В;
0;-0,273;
1;-0,039;
2;0,049;
3;0,264;
4;0,000;
5;-0,059;
6;-0,254;
7;0,039;
8;0,039;
9;0,234;
10;-0,020;
```

Список продолжается вплоть до нескольких тысяч. При построении графика возникает проблема, слишком много шумов, и всё похоже на кашу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя функция:

```
def grafic():
    try:
        plt.style.use('ggplot')  # графики
        plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 5)  # размер картинок
        file_name = fd.askopenfilename()
        f = open(file_name)
        fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', decimal=",", encoding='cp1251')
        fixed_df["Канал 0, В"].plot(figsize=(15, 10))
        f.close()
        plt.show()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        mb.showinfo("Внимание", "Файл не загружен")
```

Не могу разобраться, как в этом случае использовать метод скользящей средней?

Comment: можете выложить ваш CSV файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Выводить каждое N-ое значение - не самый лучший подход. Эти точки могут попадать на пики/выбросы и это покажет совершенно другой график, не показывающий нормальное поведение ряда.

Comment: @MaxU , https://mega.nz/file/TxcGXa7Y

Comment: @MaxU , я понимаю, что это нелогично, но всё же)

Comment: Попробуйте plot(kind='scatter') например

Comment: @MaxU , я ставил без ключа, странно

Comment: @MaxU , попробуйте эту ссылку https://mega.nz/file/TxcGXa7Y#QEIO3DpBqKO8LkH7bqLD7NXtM-TuVe22QIO55NAogTI

Comment: Вообще судя по тому как скачут значения вам надо понять что вы вообще хотите от графика. Можно скользящее среднее rolling взять за какой-то период и таким образом сгладить график, если вам это нужно. Ну либо scatter график изображать как оно есть, а не линейный как у вас, линии там не нужны при таком разбросе.

Comment: я скорее не так представил вопрос. Скорее всего нужно использовать методы скользящей средней

Comment: @is73dre Тогда делайте что-то типа fixed_df.rolling(window=3).mean() период пробуйте выбирать какой нужно. rolling это и есть скользящее окно, а дальше можно разные вещи брать, например среднюю - mean.

Comment: я тоже думаю, что скользяцее среднее позволит сгладить пики и выбросы. @CrazyElf, может оформите как ответ? ;)

Comment: @MaxU Что-то мне не до того, оформите лучше вы, если не лениво )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже [посоветовал уважаемый @CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114400/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b5-300%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment1923813_1114400), можно воспользоваться скользящим средним.

Пример:

```
df["Канал 0, В"].plot(figsize=(15, 10))
df["Канал 0, В"].rolling(50).mean().plot(figsize=(15, 10), linewidth=4)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]