# Не получается построить линейный график зависимости одной величины от даты

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график, анализ-данных

Я делаю модель ML - прогноз качества связи на основе временных рядов. Я загрузил датасет, подготовил его. Хочу построить линейный график зависимости одной величины от даты, но вместо этого у меня получается "каша" (*зам.ред.* см. скрин в истории изменений):

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime, time
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf

files = glob("/content/newDataset/*.tsv")
dataset = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", skiprows=1) for f in files], 
           ignore_index=True)

n_samples = 6992974 
dt_from = pd.to_datetime("2016-01-15 00:00:00.000000")
dt_to = pd.to_datetime("2016-01-28 23:59:59.999999")
dataset["DateTime"] = pd.date_range(dt_from, dt_to, periods=n_samples)
dataset['LQ'] = dataset.LQ.astype('float64')
dataset.head()

def plot_series(time, series, format="-", start=0, end=None, label=None):
    plt.plot(time[start:end], series[start:end], format, label=label)
    plt.xlabel("DateTime")
    plt.ylabel("LQ")
    if label:
        plt.legend(fontsize=14)
    plt.grid(True)

def trend(time, slope=0):
    return slope * time

time = dataset['DateTime']
series = dataset['LQ']
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time, series)
plt.show()
```

С чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: Код выкладывайте в виде текста.

Comment: Ссылка на colab.research.google.com, где я делаю проект, не подойдёт?

Comment: Нет. Приведите в теле вопроса в виде текста минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, отражающий проблему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Обновил пост - добавил код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь соединить отрезками почти 7 милионов точек на одном маленьком графике. Наверняка получается "каша".

В таких случаях обычно рисуют скользящее среднее (среднее в скользящем окне):

```
dataset.set_index("DateTime")["LQ"].rolling(window=1000).mean().plot()
```

PS попробуйте настроить размер окна (`window`) так, чтобы получился удовлетворяющий вас график.

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1114400/211923)

Comment: Ну, получилось более-менее. Только не понятно, а почему вместе с "LQ" рисуется ещё и "NLQ"?

Comment: @gangsta. исправил ответ - попробуйте...

Comment: То, что надо! У меня ещё такой вопрос к вам - как можете посоветовать мне сделать модель для прогноза качества связи на основе временных рядов? Стоит ли для этой цели использовать модель ARIMA?

Comment: @gangsta, уххх..., это вопрос на милион! Люди годами бьются, чтобы построить толковые модели для предсказания временных рядов. Начните с ARIMA, SARIMA (все это есть в модуле `FBProphet`). Потом можно перейти к рекуррентным нейронным сетям (LSTM) и т.д. и т.п. :-D

Comment: А вот с вашей точки зрения, по моему датасету какие задачи в маршрутизации можно решать машинным обучением?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107593/discussion-between-gangsta-and-maxu).